# NETLOGON Warning Event ID 5781

Tags: domain-name-system, windows-server-2003, netlogon

I have Server 2003 SP2 Standard Edition. This past week it has been logging an event called NETLOGON Warning 5781 at various times of the day. When this happens client computers lose access to the AD as their network folders disappear. It mentions issues with the DNS. The TCP/IP properties have no preferred DNS set - so by default the server will reference itself.

The only way to correct this issue seems to be restarting the server several times a day. I have tried editing the registry so that Netlogon is dependant on DNS as I suspected that Netlogon was starting before DNS and therefore causing the error. But now I get DNSApi error logs on the client computers.

How can I fix this? All Microsift support says is restart the server. Nothing has changed on the server in the 4 years we have had it. Then all of a sudden it throws up this error. I can't run Nltest.exe as I don't have the Serrver resource CD.

Any ideas on how to resolve this issue, please?

Comment: Even though it has been working for years without it, I'm suspicious of the lack of DNS settings on the TCP/IP properties tab for this server. Is this server also a domain controller? Is it also providing DNS for your clients?

Comment: When the issue occurs, you need to determine if you can ping the server by name and ip address.  Also, nltest is available from several other locations, including the Microsoft download center.  https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=18546